# Swiperjs with events in react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

Is there a way to attached an event with the instance of swiperjs in react? I tried using the method below but it won't recognize the on event of slideChange.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Swiper from 'swiper';

const Slider = () => {
  const swiperReference = useRef(null);

  const params = {
    on: {
      slideChange: () => {
        console.log('swiper change');
      },
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    swiperReference.current = new Swiper('.swiper-container', params);
  }, []);

  return (

<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

Answer (score 9):

**You can get the Swiper onSlideChange event the React way using the onSlideChange prop, like this:**

There's no need to instantiate Swiper in your useEffect hook. You only have to call the Swiper component in your JSX template like so:

```
      <Swiper
          className={"my-slider"}
          loop={true}
          onSlideChange={(swiperCore) => {
            const {
              activeIndex,
              snapIndex,
              previousIndex,
              realIndex,
            } = swiperCore;
            console.log({ activeIndex, snapIndex, previousIndex, realIndex });
        }}
```